# Unity3D Network Groups

Tags: unity-game-engine, network-programming

I'm just trying to make sure I understand when, why, and how to use groups when sending messages (packets or what-have-you) across the network. The example that comes to mind for me is this:

[image]

So I'm imagining this map divided into four quadrants. Let's say each quadrant has NPCs and players.
The orange star represents Network Group 1.
The red star represents Network Group 2.
The blue star represents Network Group 3.
The green star represents Network Group 4.
So let's say all players start out in the blue star quadrant of the map, they'd be in group 3. Which means that all RPCs sent with "3" as the group argument would be received and processed on all players in that quadrant client's (right?). And any RPCs sent from/to the other groups would be ignored by their client's (right)?

So if an NPC moves to a new position in the green star quadrant, it wouldn't be processed on Groups 1-3 (right)?

Now, if a player moves from the blue star quadrant, into the green star quadrant, his Network Group should be switched (via a trigger collider) from 3 to 4 (right)?

Again, I'm just trying to check my understanding of how groups work when it comes to Networking. There's not much out their in the form of tutorials and what not. At least not that I've found.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is Yes and somehow NO. There is no Network Group class. Only a Method inside the Network Class.

If you were diving in with the Network Group. You wouldn't actually Make 4 Network Groups. You only need 1 if all GameObjects is the same, However you mentioned NPC so I assume you have Players, cause it is not a game if you don't have one.

So you make 1 NetworkGroup for NPC = Because they probably have the same components. 1 NetworkGroup for Players = The same Components.

Now I think, you are concern. To individual Players having a group. Well NetworkGroup is not something like, blue team, red team etc. It is just a Grouping Objects that works with the same Components.

For having a group in your game. You should just make a variable on what team they are on.

You could make a team using NetworkGroup but it is not really relevant for Game Logic. But you can make NetworkGroup for Chat so even if they are not on the same team as long as they're in the group. You can easily call or make a chat for that Group.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. Network groups is not a class or a method...it's a variable that each Network View has. My question was answered [HERE](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/933823/networking-groups-understanding.html)